# Java Mail SMTP Hard bounce Issue

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

We are using Java Mail 1.5 API to send mails. The SMTP host we are using for development, does not have any suppression list, hence, if any emails being invalid, like "xyz@xyz.com" will be sent and though its hard bounced back, we get it in the `getInvalidAddresses()` of exception,

but if we try a prod SMTP server, which has a suppression list, the same email "xyz@xyz.com" causes the other emails to NOT being sent, if they are part of the same TO list, like "valid@domain.com; xyz@xyz.com", our expectation is at-least "valid@domain.com" should get the email, but even that is not sent and `getInvalidAddresses()` is null

`com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 254 4.7.1 -  xyz@xyz.com is suppressed for sender smtp.xxx.xxx`

```
public class SendMail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String username = "username@domain.com";
        final String password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "mysmtp.domain.com");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.sendpartial", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "25");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@domain.com"));
            message.setRecipients(
                    Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("valid@domain.com, xyz@xyz.com")
            );
            message.setSubject("Test Mail");
            message.setText("Test Mail");
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

How can we handle suppression list errors in Java Mail API?

Comment: I fail to see how this is related to Java, is this a problem with Prod SMTP, is their a code you can share, this is just a general question

Comment: @Karim I've included the code. Its related to Java Mail hence the Java tag. Its the Java Mail behaviour, why wont it send the email to other recipients, when their email ids are valid. we have even added mail.smtp.sendpartial to true

Comment: Seems like you should clean your email list and remove invalid ones?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are experiencing is caused by the return code `254` used by the e-mail server. According to [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.2.3) (the most recent embodiment of RFC 821), there is no such code. This return code seems to be an invention of [Oracle's Email Delivery](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Email/Concepts/troubleshooting.htm).

Java Mail (and its successor Jakarta Mail) interprets (cf. [source code](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/blob/226d2d6f1db283042537fa9a30dfab798649fea2/mail/src/main/java/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport.java#L1851)) unknown:

- 4xx return codes as `validUnsentAddresses`,
- 5xx return codes as `invalidAddresses`,
- 2xx return codes as complete delivery failure, since no educated guess can be done regarding the meaning of the code.

In this case the server should probably return a `550` code, meaning *"command rejected for policy reasons"*.

Comment: Thanks Piotr, I was able to catch the exception and remove the suppressed email ID. That worked for me, and you are correct, this is for Oracle SMTP server only.